# Why sync again in synchronized collection in interation?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

in the Java doc it says the synchronized collection must be manually synced again in iteration. Why is that? Since the returned collection is already synchronized. Don't quite understand why it is this way. Thank you.

```
 Collection c = Collections.synchronizedCollection(myCollection);
      ...
    synchronized(c) {
        Iterator i = c.iterator(); // Must be in the synchronized block
        while (i.hasNext())
          foo(i.next());
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Only the individual methods are synchronized. If other parts of the code are allowed to call those methods between the calls you are making in the iterator, it kills the integrity of the list, and in this case the synchronization becomes worthless.

There are perhaps some methods that are usable without needing the synchronized block with the list being wrapped using `synchronizedCollection` (such as checking how many elements are in the list), but if you are using the list and one method depends on the precise results of another called method, a synchronized block is needed around both method calls to make sure that nothing else can touch the state of the list between these calls.

Comment: Then what's the point of the synchronized collection provided by Collections? If thread A needs to first "add" one element, then need to check the 'size' of it, while thread B is also accessing the collection, potentially add or delete. In such a case, does the thread A need to locally synchronize the collection also in this case?

Comment: You can check the size of the collection while not using it in any other way (the local method synchronisation is enough). Case in point: a user interface element that displays how many players are in a game, without looking inside the collection at the actual players.

Comment: In your use case, if Thread B is only adding or removing an element, and Thread A has a synchronized block around the add then size check, there is no problem. However if there is no synchronized block, Thread B could add/remove an element before the size check, which would be problematic. The synchronized collection wrapper allows the case where Thread B does not need to explicitly specify any synchronized block.

Comment: Also, without the wrapper and without any mutual exclusion on calling methods from different threads, code may be accessed simultaneously from multiple threads that is not designed to be executed at the same time from multiple threads (e.g., there may be code that uses a local field for caching purposes). A `ConcurrentModificationException` may also be raised.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the iteration operations can't *keep* the lock on the list.  For example, `i.hasNext()` would lock the list for as long as it takes to check `hasNext()`, but then the list might get changed *again* before you can actually call `next()`.

So instead, you must lock the list yourself, to keep the whole iteration synchronized instead of just each operation individually.

Comment: “iteration operations can't keep the lock on the list”， Is that because the iteration operation is not atomic, but a series of processes？ What about if multiple threads try to add() something to the collection?

Comment: Each _method call_ is atomic, but iteration as a whole is composed of many method calls, so it can't be atomic unless you do the synchronization yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that the `iterator` loop is running in two different threads. It is perfectly legal that one thread will call `i.next().remove()` while the other thread is looping on the same `list` and this might break the consistency of the data in the list.